# How can I fix the &#39;Failed to connect&#39; error when installing Homebrew on my M1 Mac?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, apple-m1

When I try to download Homebrew on my M1 mac with this command: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
I get an error:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 8 ms: Connection refused

I tried changing my DNS to 1.1.1.1 but I couldn't for some reason. How do I solve this?

Comment: Does going to the URL in your browser work?

Comment: This is not a programming problem. It's at best a networking problem, but even then it's hardly answerable.

Comment: Matthew the url works but how do I download it from the url?